# SAPUI5 OData V2 Batch Operations with multiple differed groups

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm trying to do a batch operation with multiple groupids in a single batch request. and need to get results in two different batch responses.

But when I initiate the request only one group has been submitted and only get one batch response.

Here is my code

```
oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("mymodel");


                $.sap.itemArray.forEach(function (entry) {
                    if (p < $.sap.itemArray.length) {
                        var oData = {
                            "AUTO_ID": entry.Id,
                            "VALUE": entry.Value,

                        };
                        mParameters.groupId = "createGroup1";
                        oModel .create("/Table1", oData, mParameters);

                    }
                    p++;
                });


for (p = 0; p < $.sap.itemArray2.length; p++) {
                    var oData = {
                        "Item2ID" : $.sap.itemArray2[p].ItemsId,
                        "Value" : $.sap.itemArray2[p].Value

                    };

                    mParameters.groupId = "createGroup2";

                    oModel .create("/Table2", oData, mParameters);
                    }


    oModel.setDeferredGroups(["createGroup1","createGroup2"]);
                oStyleSizeModel.submitChanges({
                    success: function(recievedObject){
                          var responses = recievedObject.__batchResponses;
                      },
                    error: function (oError) {
                        var oBody = oError.responseText;

                    }
                });
```

Here is the response I got.

[image]

And here it only execute the first group's requests and only returned one batch response.

How to execute multiple batch requests with different group Ids and get each group's responses.

Comment: just for clareification: you want to send one batch, in that batch there multiple goup ids, then you want to get one response for each group right?

Comment: @Erch yes.. in the _batchResponses I need 2 batch responses for group 1 & group 2.. so I can identify each change responses for a specific group

Comment: it is not possible to get multiple groups into one batch. 'submitChanges' will create one batch for each deferrend group. then you should get one response for each of the batches. so basically half of what you want is possible. i guess there could be an issue with your array, try oDataModel.getDeferredGroups() and then push your strings into that array, maybe SAP has more than just the strings in that array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to group each change separately. You need to use the concept of Change Set (not Group).

1. Use [createEntry](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/createEntry) method instead of `create`.
2. For each call, use different `changeSetId`, but same `groupId`.
3. Call `submitChanges` passing the `groupId`.

Comment: is there any way to get the changeset Id from response.. 
or will the order response of changesets of the batch requests change  because if the order changed if I access batch responses by index, it won't be correct

Comment: Order of response is supposed to be the same as the request.

Comment: I tried as the answer.. it works but it creates double entires in db. What will be the issue?